# JavaScriptSerializer of JSON

Tags: c#, json

Just need some help to send a POST in C# that has the same data as the following curl

```
curl -v -u {email_address}:{password} https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user": {"name": "Roger Wilco", "email": "roge@example.org"}}'
```

I have the basic stuff below just need to change a bit not sure how... the issue is I am no sure how to create a json of {"user": {"name": "Roger Wilco", "email": "roge@example.org"}}

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://home67.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.email = this.email;
            user.name = this.name;
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);
            WriteObject(json.ToString());

// the above currently only gives {"name":"something", "email":"something@something"}

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            WriteObject(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to serialize an anonymous type with a `user` property:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { user = user });

//  {"user":{"name":"Roger Wilco","email":"roger@example.org"}}
```

Comment: how can i send this part curl -v -u {email_address}:{password}